# I have problem to select the year (python - selenium - vsCode)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, visual-studio-code

Im cannot select the year.
Run the code please an you will see what happens at the end.

```
    I've tried many ways.
    Cannot find the solution.
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from time import time
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
paginaHit = 'https://hit.com.do/solicitud-de-verificacion/'
driver.get(paginaHit)
driver.maximize_window()
embed = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "embed")
driver.switch_to.frame(embed)
bl = 'SMLU7270944A'
clasificacion = 'Mudanzas'
wait =WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "billoflanding"))).send_keys(bl)

seleccion = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "cboClasificación"))
seleccion.select_by_visible_text(clasificacion)
btnBuscar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/app-root/div/form/div/div[3]/div/button').click()

time.sleep(4)
consignatario = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'cosignatario').send_keys("LOGISTICA ADUANAL")

# seleccionMercancia = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/app-root/div/div[2]/datos-generales/form/div/div[9]/div/select'))
# seleccionMercancia.select_by_visible_text("Articulos del hogar")

condicion = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/app-root/div/div[2]/datos-generales/form/div/div[10]/div/select'))
condicion.select_by_visible_text("Verificación")

solicitante = driver.find_element(By.ID, "nombreVisitante").send_keys("JONATHAN MENDEZ GARCIA")
correo = driver.find_element(By.ID, "correo").send_keys("laduanal@gmail.com")
telefono = driver.find_element(By.ID, "telefono").send_keys("8098013610")

tipoDocumento = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/app-root/div/div[2]/datos-generales/form/div/div[16]/div/select'))
tipoDocumento.select_by_visible_text("Cédula")

cedula = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cedulaVisitante2").send_keys("00111452470")
nombreYapellido = driver.find_element(By.ID, "text01").send_keys("JONATHAN MENDEZ GARCIA")

tipoDocumento2 = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/app-root/div/visitante-form/form/div/div[3]/div/select'))
tipoDocumento2.select_by_visible_text("Cédula")

rolVisitante = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/app-root/div/visitante-form/form/div/div[4]/div/select'))
rolVisitante.select_by_visible_text("Representante")

cedulaVisitante = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cedulaVisitante").send_keys("00111452470")

btnAgregarPersonal = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/app-root/div/visitante-form/form/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/button').click()

#SELECCIONAR FECHA DE VERFICACION

fechaDeseada = "0929 2022"
fechaVerificacion = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fechaVerificar")
fechaVerificacion.send_keys(fechaDeseada)
```

The problem is in the last 3 lines of the code, but you need to run it in order to see what happen.  Will apreciate any help.  Im trying to fill up a form because is a task that need to be done all day long.

Comment: Asking StackOverflow contributors to instead run your code to see the error isn't reasonable.  As the requester, it's your responsibility to show us what's going wrong.  Can you please detail what happens when you run your code?

Comment: Thanks for you attention Dylan.  You are right, the code has no problem at all, but if you run it and wait for a while you'll see that in date field the year do not appear, that's why i wrote that the part of my code to be analyze are the 3 last lines.  See below please the 3 lines i refer to.                        
 '''                                                                                                                                       fechaDeseada = "0929 2022"
fechaVerificacion = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fechaVerificar")
fechaVerificacion.send_keys(fechaDeseada)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the date field on [hit.com.do](https://hit.com.do/) is buggy, so I had to enter the year first, then go back to entering the day & month. I'd replace your last three lines with:

```
fechaVerificacion = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fechaVerificar")
fechaVerificacion.send_keys(Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, "2022", Keys.LEFT, Keys.LEFT, "2909")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Problem solved.  Debo reconocer el aporte que hace esta comunidad en términos de ayuda y aprendizaje.  Los felicito y espero seguir aprendiendo para algún día poder aportar y ayudar como lo han hecho conmigo.